# Printing values with a specific format from dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Let’s say I have a dictionary that receives a three inputs from the user: item name, item price, and item quantity. How can I make a for-loop that produces the following:

```
Cat                      20.0              2
Dog                      30.0              3
Fish                     200.00            4
```

Here's my code:

```
grocery_list = {}
print("   MY NEW AND IMPROVED GROCERY LIST")

while True:
    def choice():  # main function
        print("======================================")
        print("What would you like to do?"
              "\n1 - Add an Item" 
              "\n2 - Remove an Item"
              "\n3 - Print entire List"
              "\n4 - Calculate Cost"
              "\n5 - Exit program")
        user = int(input("\nChoice:"))

        if user == 1:
            print("======================================"
                  "\nADD AN ITEM"
                  "\n"
                  "\nGive the following information:")
            name = str(input("Name:").lower())
            price = float(input("Price:"))
            quan = int(input("Quantity:"))
            grocery_list[name] = {"name": name, "price": price, "quan": quan}

        elif user == 2:
            print("======================================"
                  "\nREMOVE AN ITEM"
                  "\nWhat would you like to remove?")
            rmv = str(input("Item Name:").lower())

            if rmv in grocery_list:
                del grocery_list[rmv]

        elif user == 3:
            for values in grocery_list.values():
                print(values)
```

The output would then be:

```
{'name': 'cat', 'price': 2.0, 'quan': 3}
{'name': 'fish', 'price': 3.0, 'quan': 2}
```

I tried creating a for-loop but it wouldn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Your grocery_list (dict) is:

```
{
 name1: {"name": name1, "price": price, "quan": quan}, 
 name2: {"name": name2, "price": price, "quan": quan}
}
```

To iterate it, change step 3 to:

```
for item in grocery_list:
    print(grocery_list[item]['name'], grocery_list[item]['price'], grocery_list[item]['quan'])
```

Answer (score 0):

*grocery_list* is a dictionary of dictionaries. In case you want to output the values of this dictionaries, you shall once again iterate over the values of this dictionaries:

```
elif user == 3: 
    for values in grocery_list.values():
        for value in values.values()
            print(value)
```

OR if you want the exact same output you mentioned in the beginning:

```
elif user == 3: 
    for values in grocery_list.values():
        l = []
        for value in values.values()
            l.append(str(value))
        print('\t'.join(l))
```

Comment: hey, vlad! thanks for your solution. however, there's an error that says, "TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found". got any idea how i can fix the error?

Comment: @coffeegrinder Yes, you just cast your value to string like this (in the 5th line of the last code block): `l.append(str(value))`